# Windows mouse cursor resolution

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-cursor

As far as I know, Windows 10 automatically changes the size of mouse pointers (cursors) depending on the DPI settings of the display. The relations between DPI and the size of cursors are roughly as follows:

- 100% : 32x32 pixel
- 150% : 48x48 pixel
- 200% : 64x64 pixel

Can I overwrite these settings and use 100% : 64x64 pixel?

Comment: STOP editing your question to "thank you"! If the answer is OK just accept it as the answer! Or use a comment to say thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are not constantly changing dpi settings.  On Windows, you can change the size of the mouse cursor

- Open **Settings**
- Click on **Ease of Access**
- Click **Cursor & Pointer** or **Mouse Pointer** depending on your Windows version
- Use the slider to change the size

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This method scales a 32x32 pixel cursor to a larger size with a significant loss of quality and aliasing. I am asking how to make Windows use a 64x64 pixel cursor with standard dpi.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question You do not answer the question how to overwrite default Windows settings and use 100% : 64x64 pixel instead of 32x32. Delete it, please.

Comment: @senops even if it does not give the information you want, that does not mean the info is not correct or useful. You don't have to mark it as correct, but there is no cause to tell people to delete good info that IS related to the question asked.

Comment: @senops while it may not answer your question directly, it allows one to change the size of the mouse pointer.  Which I thought was your aim.  Resolution is an issue, but as far I know this is the only thing one can do.

Comment: If I drag the slider all the way to the right, I get very nice high-resolution gigantic cursors. No loss of quality whatsoever. I’m not using custom cursors though.

Comment: @DanielB Try doing this with a custom pointer, for example a MacOS pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the mouse cursor size in windows settings as Rohit Gupta explained and then change the mouse cursor to a custom one of the target resolution it works to get you a pixel perfect cursor.

I've tested it at size = 2 on the mouse options' pointer size slider and a 48x48px cursor is pixel perfect, and when size = 3 a 64x64px cursor is pixel perfect.